# What is the GnuPG process for going from a passphrase to a symmetric key?

Tags: symmetric, key-derivation, pgp

Suppose I use GnuPG to symmetrically encrypt a file like so:

```
gpg --no-options -c --cipher-algo AES256 --no-random-seed-file -o my.out my.file
```

I then provide a passphrase when prompted.

- What steps does the software actually take to get from the passphrase I provide as a user, to the actual 256-bit AES key which is used to secure the data?
- What data relating to or derived from the passphrase is stored in the output ciphertext file?
- What of the above is guaranteed by the standard, and what is implementation-defined?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GPG implements the OpenPGP standard [RFC 4880](http://tools.ietf.org/search/rfc4880), so it implements the [String-to-Key Specifiers](http://tools.ietf.org/search/rfc4880#section-3.7).

> 3.7.  String-to-Key (S2K) Specifiers
>
> String-to-key (S2K) specifiers are used to convert passphrase
>   strings    into symmetric-key encryption/decryption keys.  They are
>   used in two    places, currently: to encrypt the secret part of
>   private keys in the    private keyring, and to convert passphrases to
>   encryption keys for    symmetrically encrypted messages.
>
> 3.7.1.  String-to-Key (S2K) Specifier Types
>
> There are three types of S2K specifiers currently supported, and
>   some reserved values:
>
> ```
>    ID          S2K Type
>    --          --------
>    0           Simple S2K
>    1           Salted S2K
>    2           Reserved value
>    3           Iterated and Salted S2K
>    100 to 110  Private/Experimental S2K
> ```

I wrote my own [implementation of OpenPGP](https://github.com/calccrypto/OpenPGP/blob/master/s2k.cpp) a while back, if you dont want to search through the GPG source code. If I remember correctly, while decrypting test data I generated with GPG, I found that by default, GPG uses Iterated and Salted S2K (S2K3).

```
std::string S2K3::run(std::string pass, unsigned int sym_len){
    // get string to hash
    std::string to_hash = "";
    while (to_hash.size() < coded_count(count)){// coded count is count of bytes, not interations
        to_hash += salt + pass;
    }
    to_hash = to_hash.substr(0, coded_count(count));
    // hash string
    std::string out = "";
    unsigned int context = 0;
    while (out.size() < sym_len){
        out += use_hash(hash, std::string(context++, 0) + to_hash);
    }
    return out.substr(0, sym_len);
}
```

As for your second and third questions, I don't know. I would hope that no information of the password is stored in the file. I have tried to read the GPG source code, but failed doing so. It is very large and complex.

Comment: So if I understand you and the RFC correctly, the user-provided passphrase is basically concatenated as many times as necessary to achieve the string length defined in RFC 4880 § 3.7.1.3, hashed according to the selected S2K algorithm, and then as stated in 3.7.1.1 the selected encryption algorithm's key length number of bits is taken out of the resultant hash value. *That* data is then used as the key to encrypt the ESK packet (5.3, holding a random session key which is used to encrypt the payload), stated in 3.7.2.2. Would you say that this interpretation agrees with yours?

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I think so.